# Form Validation Disable Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the JSfiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/C7Gg3/201/

Basically i will have multiple options.

On load I need it to disable the button if any of the drop downs value = "". ( which is by default. ) I tried a document .ready function but had no success.

Then once the options all have values i want to enable the link again.

Am i on the right path?

```
    Reservation
<br/>
<select id="attribute176" name="rReservation" class="">
    <option value="">Choose a Option #1</option>
    <option value="1">Maybe</option>
    <option value="2">Sure</option>
</select><br />
<select id="attribute177" name="rReservation" class="">
    <option value="">Choose a Option #2</option>
    <option value="1">Small</option>
    <option value="2">Big</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="attribute173" name="rReservation" class="">
    <option value="">Choose a Option #3</option>
    <option value="1">Wide</option>
    <option value="2">Tall</option>
</select>
<br />
<a id="my-link" href="google.com"> GOOGLE HERE </a>
```

And the JS

```
$("[id^=attribute]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $('[id^=attribute]').addClass('required');
        $('#my-link').bind('click', false);
    } else {
        $('[id^=attribute]').removeClass('required');
        $('#my-link').unbind('click', false);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.change()` at the end of change handler like this -

```
$("[id^=attribute]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $('[id^=attribute]').addClass('required');
        $('#my-link').bind('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    } else {
        $('[id^=attribute]').removeClass('required');
        $('#my-link').unbind('click');

    }
}).change();
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/C7Gg3/209/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I checked out your JSfiddle, but when you select a option in #1 dropdown the required fields for the rest go away.

Comment: what did you change?
anyway to make the link not able to click until they are all valid? Example select option #2 and leave the rest.

Comment: Works perfect!! ill have to read on the check function! Thanks again